# How do you access the documentID in firebase when you have the data of that document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

From the code below :
data is the data of a document and i want to use that data to reference the documentID of the same document.

````
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return ProductScreen(
            // sends the id of that particular doc
            productID: data.id,
          );
        },
      ));
    },``` 
I have the data of that particular document, and i want to use that data to reference the id of the document
````

Comment: Can you show how do you get the `data` object (i.e. share the code used to get `data`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`where()`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#filtering) method in a query.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('productID', isEqualTo: "TheProductID")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.size)
    var matchedDoc = snapshot.docs
    // run a loop on matchedDoc and access the reference property
  });
```

This query will return a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) and will contain all the documents which has productID field equal to the supplied value. Then you can use `reference` property on [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html) of each document to get their [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html).

Comment: @PaaSolo welcome. If you find the answer useful you can upvote it and if it works then accept it by clicking the tick icon ;) [What should I do when someone answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: But the Product ID is rather a required field in the ProductScreen class which requires the Document id of that product

Comment: @PaaSolo I'm confused. Are you trying to get a document by using a field value? or do you already have to snapshot and are trying to get document ID?

Comment: I want to pass the document ID of that product to the Product ID but i can't retrieve it although i know the data in the document

Comment: @PaaSolo are you saying document ID and product ID are same? If yes then you need to run the query on any other field.